# Is it/when will it be safe to release apps with Google Cloud Storage using JSON API?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I've noticed that the JSON API for Google Cloud Storage is, as it says, "Experimental", and that the URL's I'm supposed to use all have 'v1beta2' in it. It looks like it hasn't been touched since May 7th, and I'm wondering if it's worth creating a new project with this service as primary storage service if I'd want my app to go live in a month or two. Is there a release date somewhere, or is it more like "it'll take as long as it takes"-kinda thing?

*Please don't downvote, I wanted to ask this in Google Cloud's own forum as this isn't a programmatic question, but as it turns out - their forum is linking me here to SO asking me to tag with 'google storage' for anything related to it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Cloud Storage JSON API is marked "experimental" to mark it as an exception to our deprecation policy. As we bring it to full release, there is a chance we may make some changes to the API, and this is why you see the special URLs. We don't have a date yet for full release. You should be able to use it just fine, if you are prepared to migrate your app to the official API when it is released.

Comment: Thanks. So, hard-coding an URL containing '/v1beta2/' into my app isn't exactly the best solution..

Comment: If you're using v1beta2, you should go ahead and hardcode v1beta2. If you don't, assumptions you make about the nature of the API might change, and your applications might fail in subtle and interesting ways.